# Python OPCUA wrong SourceTimestamp

Tags: python, server, timestamp, opc-ua

I currently stuck at a DataValue (wrong SourceTimestamp) problem.

my OPCUA Server (programmed in python) has a variable with the following DataValue:

```
DataValue(Value:Variant(val:36,type:VariantType.Int64), StatusCode:StatusCode(Good), SourceTimestamp:2021-06-04 14:22:47.425125)
```

In my client, the SourceTimestamp is 2 hours earlier (due to timezones) and there is None server Timestamp.

How can I change the SourceTimestamp? I figured that I need to do it with

```
.set_data_value()
```

However, I don´t get the syntax behind it. What does self mean?

```
def set_value(self, value, varianttype=None):
```

Also, how can I show the ServerTimestamp?

All tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `set_value` API doesn't support setting timestamps directly (at least AFAIK). The solution is passing an instance of `opcua.ua.DataValue` instead of the "real" value.

This means, instead of something like this:

```
node.set_value(42)
```

You pass an instance of `DataValue` with the desired timestamp. I.e. something along these lines:

```
# Just an example. Use the time that makes sense for you
timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()  

# NOTE: here you can pass 'serverTimestamp' as well.
datavalue = ua.DataValue(variant=42, sourceTimestamp=timestamp)
node.set_value(datavalue)
```